# Why do we use the (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:0) query for the selection of devices using Mozilla Browser?

Tags: css, media-queries, mozilla, visual-web-developer, devicepixelratio

I was working on a plugin and got a very basic question in mind, would be really grateful if someone can help me out with it. Why exactly do we use (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:0) query and how does it differ from the other queries. How does it specifically select only the mozilla browser. Are there any alternatives that have appeared in the recent times?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative targeting FF Mozilla FireFox:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix('') {body {background-color: red;}}
```

> [@document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document#browser_compatibility)
>
> Only supports an empty url-prefix() value, which is supported due to
> its use in Firefox browser detection. Still supported in user
> stylesheets.